# Fetching last incomplete record or new in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Rails 3.2.21 app where I'm adding some basic timeclock functionality. I need to build a scope called `current_clock_event` that will look for the last record for a user where `clock_out: nil` so in essence, the record that will be fetched is the last `ClockEvent` record for the user that does not have a value in `clock_out`.  This is what I want to pass to my controller/view.

```
class ClockEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :clock_in, :clock_out, :total_hours, :user_id 

  scope :current_clock_event, where(clock_out: NIL).last
end
```

As you can see I wrote a very simple scope to pull a record where the `clock_out: NIL` so in theory that should pull the last incomplete record.  I think this is working ok but I need to figure out how to access this in the controller and have some sort of conditional to either pull the `current_clock_event` or instantiate a new clock event if the last record is completed (both `clock_in` and `clock_out` are populated)

So I'm stubbing out my controller but am hitting a wall as to how to do this.

```
class ClockEventsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @clock_event = current_user.current_clock_event # need to figure out this part to fetch the record or if the record is complete instantiate a ClockEvent.new for the user.
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

I wrote code 2 years ago that did all of this but lost the repo by accident so I have nothing to reference and am sort of brain-fogging on how to pull this off.

Any help would be appreciated.  If you need more examples or further explanation, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something like this:

```
class ClockEvent

  belongs_to :user

  # you might want to add an order here...
  scope :last_clock_event, -> { where("clock_out NULL").last }

  def completed?
    clock_in.present? && clock_out.present?
  end

end

class User

  has_many :clock_events

  def current_clock_event
    ce = clock_events.last_clock_event
    ce.completed? ? ClockEvent.new : ce
  end

end

class ClockEventsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @clock_event = current_user.current_clock_event
    render :index
  end

end
```

The `completed?` method defined on the `ClockEvent` instance allows you to tell if your instance is considered completed or not.

The `current_clock_event` method defined at the `User` level allows you to define the logic to return either the last clock event record or a new one if completed.

The `index` method is pretty straight forward.

Comment: This is actually a really good way to handle this.  I had been so focused on the controller and putting the logic in there, that I didn't think of handling it on the model side.  So this should allow me to pass in `@clock_event` to my form on the index action and will allow them to clock in/out either on the incomplete event or a new event all together.  Just making sure I'm reading this right.  I like the solution, I'm going to give it a shot today and will report back :)  Many thanks!

Comment: What about something like this (see answer I'm posting)

Comment: Sorry about the formatting on my answer, but hopefully you get the gist of what I'm trying to do.  I'm taking the clock event and caching it to memory in a variable to avoid excessive db hits, and I'm defining the behavior in the `clock_event` method to either look at the last incomplete `ClockEvent` or instantiate a new `ClockEvent`

Comment: sounds good. use `build` instead of `new` here `clock_events.new`

Comment: Gotcha.  I thought `build` was just an alias to `new`.  Is there a benefit of using it over the latter?

Comment: It's an alias, just rails conventions :)

Comment: Roger that, I'll stick with conventions :)

Answer (score 0):

I played around with some code and was able to get some refactoring help to make things cleaner.  In the `User` model I refactored `current_clock_event` to just `clock_event` and seem to have been able to make the code a bit cleaner, although it's not tested, just stubbed out for now.  Let me know what you think.

```
 class ClockEvent
   belongs_to :user

   scope :incomplete, -> { where(clock_out: nil) }
   scope :complete, -> { where.not(clock_out: nil) }

   def completed?
     clock_in.present? && clock_out.present?
   end
  end

  class User
    has_many :clock_events

     def clock_event
      @clock_event ||= clock_events.incomplete.last || clock_events.new
     end
   end

  class ClockEventsController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @clock_event = current_user.clock_event
      render :index
    end
  end
```